# jquery autocomplete rendering hidden div

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have been trying to get jquery.autocomplete (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) to work for the last few hours and can't get past this issue.  It keeps rendering a hidden div containing the ul.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  The ul contains the appropriate data....

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What do you mean with a 'hidden div'? Could you post the _relevant_ code you're using at this point? Otherwise it's very hard to determine what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont u try this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ .